# R Programming Data Type Conversion

Tags: r, variables, callback, type-conversion

```
 # Assigning a value to the variable my_apples
my_apples <- 5 

# Fixing the assignment of my_oranges
my_oranges <- "six" 

# Creating the variable my_fruit and printing it out
my_fruit <- my_apples + my_oranges 
my_fruit
```

Trying to add "apples" and "oranges" by assigning a text value to the variable my_oranges.
Pls help me with this.

Comment: Are you looking for `help("c")`? Please read An Introduction to R.

Comment: what's the desired outcome for `my_fruit`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a numeric value and a text value for a addition. if both variables are numeric/integer you can sum up the values. If both variables are string, you can add them using paste()

```
my_apples <- 5 


# Fixing the assignment of my_oranges
my_oranges <- 6

# Creating the variable my_fruit and printing it out
my_fruit <- my_apples + my_oranges 


my_apples <- "five"


# Fixing the assignment of my_oranges
my_oranges <- "six"

# Creating the variable my_fruit and printing it out
my_fruit <- paste0(my_apples,my_oranges)
```

you can see ?paste function and look on to collapse and sep arguments

Comment: You can make addition only for numeric values. as already informed. paste function helps you to make concatenate .                                          
   x = "I love"     y = "stackoverflow"   z = paste(x,y) will print these statements all together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro. Can we use as.characer() in this to do some related calculations

Comment: as.character will convert the string to character.  look on the link to learn R                             
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-scratch/

Comment: thanks bro..x<- c(1:100). Pls help me in getting output of range of number from 41-50

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-c(1:100)
x[41:50] will give you the output. everything is a list in r.
```

Comment: no bro, i need to get output of number starting with 4 .